# Is $h(x_1,...,x_n)=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

How would I go about showing whether or not $h(x_1,...,x_n)=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$ is continuous?

I have shown that the partial derivatives exist everywhere except $(0,..,0)$.

Comment: How is the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ described?

Comment: I don't study topology unfortunately

Comment: I think it's the [standard topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_topology#Definition_and_uses).

Comment: Well, you still must know what "continuous" means, so you must have some description of the topology. Depending on which description you have, the proof is more or less easy.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $h$ simply represents the euclidean norm of the vector $(x_1, \ldots,x_n)^T$. It therefore satisfies all axioms of a norm and I would like to refer you to this article [Why are norms continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265284/why-norms-are-continuous-with-details) to find your answer.

Answer (score 2):

$h$ is just the $l_2$-norm, it is a continuous function in virtue of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Or: $h^2$ is a non-negative polynomial function, hence its square root is well-defined and continuous.

Answer (score 0):

for partial derivate we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{u}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u$, wich gives for $a\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$:

$$h_a(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}=\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2)}{2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}}=\frac{x_a}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}}$$

then if $h_a(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ is continuos at $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(0,0,\cdots,0)$ then  the limit $(1)$ exists:

$$\lim_{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\to(0,\cdots,0)}h_a(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\tag{1}$$

lets proof that the limite $(1)$ does not exists, taking the path $x_a=x$ and $x_i=0,i\ne a$, then $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto(0,\cdots,0)=x\mapsto0$

$$\lim_{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\to(0,\cdots,0)}h_a(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{|x|}$$

since

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{|x|}=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{x}{|x|}=-1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{|x|}\ne\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{x}{|x|}$$

then the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{|x|}=\nexists$ wich implies that the limit $(1)$ does not exists and then $h_a(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is not continuos at $(0,\cdots,0)$

to proof the continuity on other points, since $h(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ are continuos and $x_a$ is continuos and for all $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\ne(0,0,\cdots,0)\Rightarrow h(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\ne0$, then $h_a(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\frac{x_a}{h(x_1,\cdots,x_n)}$ is continuos for all $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\ne(0,0,\cdots,0)$