# Upper and lower Semicontinuous function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $f(x)=\|x\|^2$ in Hilbert space into positive real numbers space
I try to prove the $f$ is continuous by the theorem that say $f$ is continuous iff it upper semicontinuous and lower semicontinuous, I want a hint to prove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are norms continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265284/why-are-norms-continuous)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your questions lacks details and context. Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far? You can find some remarks about how to ask a good question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Also try to use MathJax to increase the readability of your question.

Comment: Thank you I see it but if f(x) equal sequar of norm x