# Understanding the proof to continuity of norms in normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Following the proof outlined here
[Why are norms continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265284/why-are-norms-continuous/265595#265595),

this is what I expected to be shown:
$\forall \epsilon >0,\, \exists \delta>0,\, \mid\mid x-y \mid\mid<\delta \, \Rightarrow 
  $
$\mid\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid\mid< \epsilon\,\,$  where $f$ represents the norm function.

Instead, the given proof aims to show $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid <\epsilon.$

In other words, instead of proving that $\biggl|\biggl| \mid\mid x \mid\mid- \mid\mid y \mid\mid \biggl|\biggl| <\epsilon,
$ the given proof ends with showing $\biggl| \mid\mid x \mid\mid- \mid\mid y \mid\mid \biggl|<\epsilon$.

Why instead of using the (arbitrary) norm as a metric for measuring the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, the absolute value is used? Perhaps I am missing something about the definition of continuity in a normed spaced, here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that $f$ is real-valued, being a norm. We are showing $f$ is continuous using the absolute value norm in the codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this crystal clear, let us recall the definition of continuity in metric spaces:

$$f: A \to B$$ is uniformly continuous if 
$$\forall \epsilon >0,\, \exists \delta>0,\,  d_A(x,y)<\delta \, \Rightarrow d_B(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$$

Since in your case $f: (E, \| \, \|) \to (\mathbb R, | \, |)$ you have  $$d_A(x,y)=\| x -y\|\\
d_B(a,b)=|a-b|$$

Answer (score 1):

The norm is a function $||\cdot||_X:X\to [0,\infty)$. Hence if you define $f(x)=||x||_X$, then $f(x)$ is a real positive number. In $\mathbb{R}$, the norm is the usual euclidean norm which is simply the absolute value, so $||f(x)-f(y)||_\mathbb{R}=\big|||x||-||y||\big|$ :)
If you have any questions, let me know !