# Is $||f(x)-f(y)||$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis

am reading a long proof and I don’t get if this is true:

Let |||| be the Euclidean metric. If I show a function 
f
 is continuous. Will =||()−()||

be continuous? I am guessing yes because ℎ=()−()

is continuous.

So if g()is continuous

is $a(x)=||g(x)|| $ also continuous ? This should be very ba

Edit: is the metric a contour function? Assume $d$ is a metric on a set, so will the metric be continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't let me comment so I can't really have a conversation to work out the proper answer. It depends on what kind of norm you are using. If you are referring to an operator norm between two normed F-vector spaces, then typically one refers to bounded linear operators which are continuous, this can include $n \times n$ matrices, derivatives (within stricter constraints), integral transformations and much more.

If you are referring to a norm on function spaces rather than operator spaces, this other question may help

[Why are norms continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265284/why-are-norms-continuous)

So in other words, it depends on the context, but if you're looking through material in a class there are conventional theorems you can rely on. A metric immediately follows from a norm, that is, for any normed F vector space, $|| x-y ||$ generates a metric topology and so you can use $||x-y||$ as the metric.

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. Sorry if my question was asked in a confusing manner

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.