# Metric-completion of a normed space is canonically a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have given the following theorem

> Let $X$ be a metric space, with metric completion $\bar{X}$, and $Y$ be a complete metric space. Then a uniformly continuous map $f: X \to Y$ extends uniquely to $\bar{X}$.

which I want to use to show that

> the metric-completion of a normed space is canonically a Banach space.

Obviously $\bar{X}$ is complete and normed, but I do not find a way to proof that $\bar{X}$ is a normed vector space, i.e. that $(\bar{+}): \bar{X} \times \bar{X} \to \bar{X}$ is continuous in that norm.
The way to go should be to proof that $(+): X \times X \to \bar{X}$ is uniformly continuous and then use the theorem stated above, but the uniform continuity of $(+)$ is where I stuck.

Comment: Is $X$ a normed space? And $\tilde{X}, Y$?

Comment: @ε-δ doesn't the metric induce norms on all three of them by defining $\Vert x \Vert = d(0,x)$ ?

Comment: Of course not. What is $0$ in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: @ε-δ You got a got point there, unfortunately this is all the information the exercise provides me with. Let me think about this and try to fix the gaps.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the question "What is $0$ in an arbitrary metric space ": $X$ is a normed space and $0\in X\subset \overline X$

Comment: @DiegoG7 It is not given that $X$ is normed, let alone a vector space.

Comment: Ah wait I misread. Nevermind my previous comments!

Comment: You said "the metric-completion of a normed space is canonically a Banach space." Isn't $X$ a vector space and $0$ the neutral element?

Comment: However, I think that this link is useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265284/why-are-norms-continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use that result as is, simply because the domain of $+$ is not $X$, but $X \times X$. You would really need to show that $\overline{X} \times \overline{X}$ is really the closure of $X \times X$. Of course, to do that, you'd need to nominate an appropriate norm (or a metric, at least) on $X \times X$.

I'm not convinced that it's worth doing. Instead, recall (or prove) that the sum of Cauchy sequences is Cauchy. Note that, if $(x_n), (y_n), (z_n)$ are Cauchy sequences with $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ equivalent, i.e. $\|x_n - y_n\| \to 0$, then $(x_n + z_n)$ and $(y_n + z_n)$ are equivalent (pretty obviously). This gives us a well-defined $+$ operation on the completion: $[x_n] + [y_n] := [x_n + y_n]$. You can do something similar with scalar multiplication.

Next comes the legwork. You have to show that $\overline{X}$ is a vector space with respect to the two operations. That means verifying **all** the axioms of a vector space, bar none. It's not a subspace of a known vector space, so you can't just show closure and non-emptiness.

You can use the theorem to extend the norm of $X$ to $\overline{X}$ (note that $\|\cdot\|$ is uniformly continuous, as $|\|x\| - \|y\|| \le \|x - y\|$). You then need to prove that this is a norm, using the axioms.

To conclude completeness, simply note that the metric on $\overline{X}$ agrees with the norm metric. You know that the completion is complete, hence $\overline{X}$ will therefore be a Banach space under the given norm.

I've brushed over **a lot** of detail! It's too much for me to write out, but none of it is tricky. In fact, most of it follows directly from $X$ being a vector space.